# Unit nfs-common.service is masked

Tags: nfs

This error seems to have occurred after erasing and recreating the user of uid 1000.
How do we deal with this?

error image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TShir.png)

Answer (score 8):

Check /lib/systemd/system/nfs-common.service with ls -l and delete /dev/null symbolic links

rm /lib/systemd/system/nfs-common.service

systemctl daemon-reload